# Spring Web Services: <sws:annotation-driven /> as Java configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, configuration, spring-ws

I want to migrate from XML based configurations to Java based. What would be the equivalent of `<sws:annotation-driven />` (Spring Web Services) in Java configuration?

Thank you very much!